# Print value until string index is 0

Tags: python

I am passing dot separated key as a argument. I have used `split(".")` and then print the value data. Here is my code:

```
desc = str(sys.argv[1])
st = desc.split(".")
i = 0
print (len(st))
for i in range(len(st)):
  for ch in st:
    st[i] = ch
    print (st[i])
    i += 1
    print(i)

#print(data[st1][st2]..[stn])
```

I am getting the output as

```
3
db
1
dap
2
nodes
3
db
2
db
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getvar.py", line 17, in <module>
    st[i] = ch
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I want the `data[db][dap][nodes]` which will give me the correct value. How should I proceed?

Comment: how the output should look like ?

Comment: This task should not involve two nested loops. There is much too much going on, especially with `i`. You simply need, for each element of st, to jump down one level in data: `result = data; for e in st: result = result[e]`.

Comment: The output will be the config.toml value, so the value of data[db][dap][nodes]=['cluster1:15382', 'cluster2:15382'] and there are keys, for eg: data[path][repo]=/home/user1

Comment: What is in `sys.argv[1]`?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing 2 loops : for item in items and for i in range.
When you use `i in range` the max value in length -1 because indexes are zero based.
when you have used split st is an array of values so the line `st[i] = ch` is reloading the value back where is was read from.
Here I give both syntaxes of the loop. You will observe that `print(st)` before the loops gives the result that you want.

```
desc="10.12.45.35.66.28"
#desc = str(sys.argv[1])
st = desc.split(".")
print([st])
print ("length:",len(st))

for j in range(len(st)-1):
    print (j," -> ", st[j])  
    
i = 0    
for ch in st:
    st[i] = ch
    print (i," -> ", st[i])
    i += 1
```